# Why is cis-1,2-dichloroethene more stable than trans-1,2-dichloroethene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, stability, cis-trans-isomerism

> Why is *cis*-1,2-dichloroethene more stable than *trans*-1,2-dichloroethene?

Usually, trans compunds are more stable than cis ones, due to less strain and its non-polarity. But, in this case it's quite the opposite. I tried to search the reason behind it, and found that it's supposedly due to the [*cis* effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cis_effect)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a **pre-MOT rationalisation** of the *cis* form being more stable than the *trans* form for 1,2-dihaloethylenes:

The lone pair of chlorine atoms is involved in resonance with the double bond, as it does so positive charge appears on one chlorine and negative on another. A *cis* geometry allows for a stabilizing interaction (attraction) between these positive and negative charges, which makes this resonance form a greater contributor to the resonance hybrid than it is for the *trans* isomer.

[image: Resonance structures of 1,2-dichloroethene]

**MOT-based explanation:**

Eyring's work suggests that there is *maximum delocalisation possible in trans form*.

Quoting, from the same paper:

> In a recent paper Binghams proposes that the main effect responsible for the “cis effect” of ethylenes is *an effect which tends to destabilize the trans form rather than provide extra stabilization for the cis form*. In short, this is an unfavorable conjugation effect which stems from the fact that the conjugation in these cases is between two filled orbitals (halogen lone pair and $\pi$ bond). The interaction gives rise to two new orbitals, one bonding and one antibonding, *the latter being more antibonding than the former is bonding*. Consequently, the **total interaction is energetically unfavorable**, in contrast to interaction in hydrocarbon polyenes. This would be equally true for both the *cis* and *trans* forms but, following Eyring’s argument, the delocalization is greater in the *trans* form.
>   Consequently this form will be the less stable one.

---

Reference: [Structure of 1,2-difluorocyclopropane and the "cis effect"](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00509a009?journalCode=jacsat)

Answer (score 10):

In this answer, I will point out an inadequacy of the reasoning based on resonance structures and I will also provided another MO perspective, which I believe is more convincing, on the issue.

**A flaw in the resonance argument**

As presented by Abcd, the phenomenon can be explained without use of MO theory and purely based on resonance structures. Please refer to his answer for the argument. Based on this argument, we may actually expect the $\ce {C=C}$ double bond to become weakened. Since if the two zwitterionic resonance structures were to be significant, the central double bond should naturally have less double bond character and more single bond character. However, data presented by Skancke & Boggs (1979) show that the $\ce {C-C}$ bond length is in fact shorter in the *cis* isomer ($\pu{1.311 Å}$) than in the *trans* isomer ($\pu{1.320 Å}$)$^1$. This suggests that the resonance stabilisation may not be the cause of this phenomena.

**Another MO perspective**

Fleming (2009) provides an explanation which I feel is more convincing. Essentially, the idea is that extra stabilisation in the cis form is derived from the interaction between the antiperiplanar $\ce {C-H}$ $\sigma$ and the low-lying  $\ce{C-Cl}$ $\sigma^*$ MOs. Jan provides more details on this [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39102/how-can-the-gauche-effect-be-explained) when he explains the cause of a similar effect responsible for the gauche conformation being favoured in 2-fluoroethanol. Another phenomenon that Fleming touches on which he uses the same explanation for is the preference for the gauche conformation in 1,2-difluoroethane. It is also explained in the same paragraph on p. 89.

The same explanation can be used for 1,2-dichloroethene. This is because chlorine is also a rather electronegative atom, although less so than fluorine. Thus, we can still expect the $\ce {C-Cl}$ $\sigma^*$ MO to be low enough in energy to interact with the the $\ce {C-H}$ $\sigma$ MO.

---

**References**

1. Skancke, A.; Boggs, J. E. Structure of 1,2-Difluorocyclopropane and the "Cis Effect". *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1979,** *101* (15), 4063–4067. 
   [doi:10.1021/ja00509a009](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00509a009)
2. Fleming, I. Molecular Orbitals and Organic Chemical Reactions. John Wiley & Sons, Ltd. United Kingdom, **2009**.